# compliant variable length struct in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, standards, standards-compliance

In standard C you can end a struct with an array of size 0 and then over allocate it to add a variable length dimension to the array:

```
struct var
{
    int a;
    int b[];
}

struct var * x=malloc(sizeof(var+27*sizeof(int)));
```

How can you do that in C++ in a standard (portable) way?
It is okay to have a constraint of max posible size and obviously doesn't have to work on the stack

I was thinking of:

```
class var
{
...
private:
  int a;
  int b[MAX];
};
```

and then use allocators or overload new/delete to under allocate based on the required size:

(sizeof(var) - (MAX-27)*sizeof(int)

But, while it seems to work, its not something I'd want to have to maintain.

Is there a cleaner way that is fully standard/portable?

Comment: Technically no, though the "struct hack" (declaring it with size 1, then over-allocating as you see fit) works with nearly all compilers. There's been talk of a `dynarray` type that did things vaguely like this, but I believe they've voted against including it in C++14 (and it definitely doesn't exist in C++98, 03 or 11).

Comment: Insert the "Unwarranted chumminess with the implementation" quote here...

Comment: you should be looking into using the STL for this kind of requirements.

Comment: Never tried this, but you may be able to use `offsetof` and have the last item be a pointer which points to the overflow.

Comment: @JerryCoffin +1 - the issue is that any data past b[0] is then technically "untyped" and as such becomes implementation defined behavior.  By walking backwards, the data is properly typed.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: Sure, in theory. In actual practice, however, the only noticeable difference is that declaring a size of 1 makes the math simpler.

Comment: You could always make the size a template parameter.

Comment: @SB. That wouldn't respect the possibility of padding or implementation-managed data after the last member.

Comment: Since when is this standard C? You need to declare the last member as `int b[];` to get a flexible array member; using a 0-length array is a nonstandard extension.

Comment: +1 -- old habits die hard, my fingers just added the 0 :) -- will edit, thanks

Comment: @JerryCoffin - using MAX allows a safety net for allocation on the stack or inheritence - it'll work - but will waste some space.   On the other hand, using the "struct hack" will likely cause a core dump in that case and force the offender to rethink their code :)

Comment: seems a bit superfluous in C++ with standard dynamic containers like vector - the whole point with this construction in C was to make the structure dynamic.

Comment: @claptrap: it also brings memory locality and a single allocation (for the whole struct at once).

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: If you use the struct hack in C++, I encourage you to declare the thing `final` to avoid spurious inheritance. It should work anyway...

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes but it is simple to add a ctor to give you a single allocation with a vector as member and much cleaner having in mind that his main concern was portability.

Comment: @claptrap actually the goal was single contiguous allocation (as the C var struct gave) - the contraint was standard and portable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with simply doing a variant of the C way?

If the structure has to remain purely POD, the C way is fine.

```
struct var
{
    int a;
    int b[1];

    static std::shared_ptr<var> make_var(int num_b) {
        const extra_bytes = (num_b ? num_b-1 : 0)*sizeof(int);
        return std::shared_ptr<var>(
                new char[sizeof(var)+extra_bytes ],
                [](var* p){delete[]((char*)(p));});
}
```

since it's a POD, everything works just like it did in C.

---

If `b` is not guaranteed to be POD, then things get more interesting.  I haven't tested any of it, but it would look more or less like so.  Note that `make_var` relies on `make_unique`, because it uses a lambda destructor.  You can make it work without this, but it's more code.  This works just like the C way, except it cleanly handles variable amounts of types with constructors and destructors, and handles exceptions

```
template<class T>
struct var {
    int a;

    T& get_b(int index) {return *ptr(index);}
    const T& get_b(int index) const {return *ptr(index);}

    static std::shared_ptr<var> make_var(int num_b);
private:
    T* ptr(int index) {return static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(&b))+i;}
    var(int l);
    ~var();
    var(const var&) = delete;
    var& operator=(const var&) = delete;

    typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), std::alignof(T)>::type buffer_type;
    int len;
    buffer_type b[1];
};
template<class T> var::var(int l)
    :len(0)
{
    try {
        for (len=0; len<l; ++len)
            new(ptr(i))T();
    }catch(...) {
        for (--len ; len>=0; --len)
            ptr(i)->~T();
        throw;
    }
}
template<class T> var::~var()
{
    for ( ; len>=0; --len)
        ptr(i)->~T();
}
template<class T> std::shared_ptr<var> var::make_var(int num_b)
{
    const extra_bytes = (num_b ? num_b-1 : 0)*sizeof(int);
    auto buffer = std::make_unique(new char[sizeof(var)+extra_bytes ]);
    auto ptr = std::make_unique(new(&*buffer)var(num_b), [](var*p){p->~var();});
    std::shared_ptr<var> r(ptr.get(), [](var* p){p->~var(); delete[]((char*)(p));});
    ptr.release();
    buffer.release;
    return std::move(r);
}
```

Since this is untested, it probably doesn't even compile, and probably has bugs.  I'd normally use `std::unique_ptr` but I'm too lazy to make proper standalone deleters, and `unique_ptr` is hard to return from a function when the deleter is a lambda.  On the off chance you want to use code like this, use a proper standalone deleter.

Comment: so that you can't leak the memory.  Use smart pointers instead of raw pointers for owning resources

Answer (score 2):

While this is not directly answering your question -- I would point to that a better practice in C++ is to use the STL lib for this sort of variable length array -- it is safe and simpler and understood by anybody who will maintain it after you.

```
class var
{
...
private:
  int a;
  std::vector<int> b; // or use std::deque if more to your liking
};
```

Now you can just new it up like any other class;

```
var* myvar = new var;
```

And you can use it just like a old type array without explicitly allocating the memory (although that is not what most ++ programmers do)

```
myvar->b[0] = 123;
myvar->b[1] = 123;
myvar->b[2] = 123;
```

Comment: std::vector is overkill, since just having a pointer would do the same thing.  Unfortunately this means that the class is no longer POD and has a lot of unneeded overhead since once constructed the size never changes

Comment: All good points, but to continue "...and you can't share them between processes via shared memory, nor do a naive binary read or write of the object, or pass it to C code, or overlay it on data from a network packet that you wish to parse etc...."

Comment: @Potatoswatter -- there is no explicit reason to use new -- it is just an example of ways to do stuff without having anything funny going on.

Comment: @TonyD -- while that is true, then they are edge cases, and the OPs question was not asking for C integration or network buffer management, but for a cleaner and portable way of handling variable size data.

Comment: @Soren: well, the question asks for a clean portable way to do the dynamic-array-at-end-of-struct hack, not for an alternative, so we can only speculate on whether there're functional reasons the OP needs to stick with that model....  Great to have alternatively listed though, and 95% chance they'll suit.

Comment: @Soren `new` *is* something funny going on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, although you can't declare it as an array member. You can use a reference:

```
struct s {
    int ( & extra_arr )[];

    s() : extra_arr( reinterpret_cast< int (&)[] >( this[1] ) {}
};
```

In practice this will use a pointer's worth of storage, although in theory it doesn't need to. This class is not POD, attributable to that difference between theory and practice.

---

You can alternately put the `reinterpret_cast` into a nonstatic member function:

```
struct s {
    int ( & get_extra() )[]
        { return reinterpret_cast< int (&)[] >( this[1] ); }

    int const ( & get_extra() const )[]
        { return reinterpret_cast< int const (&)[] >( this[1] ); }
};
```

Now access requires function call syntax (inlining will eliminate the distinction in machine code besides the debug build), but there is no wasted storage and the object will be POD barring some other exception to the POD rules.

With a little ABI tweaking such as `#pragma pack` this can get you full C binary compatibility. Often such tweaking is needed for serialization applications anyway.

Also this one supports const-correctness, whereas the previous solution allows modification of a const object (because it's unaware that the array is part of the same object).

The boilerplate can be generalized into a CRTP base class (which in C++11 even still allows the derived class to be POD), or a preprocessor macro expanding to define either the C++ accessor or the C flexible member.

---

Note that neither of these solutions does anything more than the original C. The special member functions will not copy the flexible array, and the class cannot support a function parameter or subobject.

Comment: "and the object may be POD"... the "logical" object now has state outside the memory region the compiler's aware of, so most of the things POD implies work would still be broken.

Comment: @TonyD Those things (namely copying by `memcpy(…, sizeof (T))`) don't work with flexible arrays anyway when using C. POD essentially guarantees that C operations and constructs continue to work the same way they do in C, and that still follows when using my second solution. You just have to do a little extra address and size computation when doing byte-wise memory manipulation.

Comment: How is this an improvement over b[MAX]?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum See my comment on uk4321's answer. `b[MAX]` is very broken in C++ because the entire worst-case array needs to be allocated every time. (Not doing so would be too risky for actual practice.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: of which "C operations and constructs" do you speak, that will work with the implementation you've suggested?

Comment: @TonyD Calling `extern` functions implemented in C including the standard library such as `memcpy`. What else is there?

Comment: My point is that saying "the object may be POD" suggests not only that memcpy etc. can be manually used on the objects, but that the compiler-generated copy constructor, assignment operator, destructor etc. are sufficient.  Saying "don't work with flexible arrays anyway when using C" doesn't make your implementation more POD like.  I just think the claim's going to confuse readers ;-.

Comment: @TonyD Perhaps "may be" sounds wishy washy. I mean that unless you do something else to make it non POD, it is going to POD, because non-virtual non-special member functions do not affect POD-ness. You can safely put my code in an `#if __cplusplus` against an `int extra_arr[]` member for C translation units and you're good to go, as long as the ABI for flexible arrays calls for allocation starting at the same byte that `this[1]` points to. That's easy enough to arrange with minimal knowledge of the ABI, which one needs to make these things (like parsing network packets) work anyway.

Comment: @TonyD The semantics that in C++ are supplied by the copy constructor and assignment operator are not supported by the native operators for flexible arrays in C. Nor can a flexible array be passed by value. That's part of their usage, which a user has to know before using them. The constructor and destructor are defined to do nothing for POD objects (or in any case the implementation cannot require that they be run).

Comment: Is this really a standards compliant use of `reinterpret_cast`? The cast may be legal but actually using `extra_arr` may not be legal.

Comment: "The semantics... for flexible arrays" - that's my point!  Saying "the object may be POD" + effectively "well, as POD as flexible arrays (which aren't very POD at all)" is a strange claim :-).  Anyway, we both obviously agree that neither flexible arrays nor your approach allow `POD f(POD arg)` style usage, but do allow `memcpy`.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Yes, as long as the array element is a POD type (as `int` is) its lifetime begins once memory is allocated, i.e. `malloc` returns, and a value is assigned to it. Otherwise you need to resort to something like `std::uninitialized_fill`.

Comment: @TonyD It depends what you ask of POD and object value semantics. I interpret the question as request for a C++ compatibility layer for use with C, not a user-friendly and fully encapsulated extension. The OP seems pretty clear he just wants a flexible array in C++.

Comment: As well as compatibility with C specifically, there are many other uses of such structures including overlaying for convenient interpretation of data received via I/O, and as an optimisation compared to a `std::vector<>` member.  Anyway, I agree that's all the question asks for, just not that any implementation C++ allows is particularly POD like.  No worries though... said my bit every which way I can think of  ;-).

Comment: @Potatoswatter, you are violating the "strict aliasing rule" of C++. The cast is legal and will compile, but result of using `extra_arr` to access an object in memory is "undefined." Please see section 3.10.10 of the standard.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod There is no aliasing because the memory for the array is never accessed as anything other than that array. That memory is unused and uninitialized until array members are assigned, whereupon `int` object lifetimes begin. Accessing `this[1]` *without* a `reinterpret_cast` would violate strict aliasing, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <size_t MAX>
class var
{
   ...
private:
  int a;
  int b[MAX];
};
```

In each template instantiation MAX is a constant that can be used on loops. Then you can construct vars whith any length.

```
var<7> v7;
var<100> v100;
```

Or typedef them

```
typedef var<10> myVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way is to use inheritance:

```
class Parent
{
  public:
    virtual int get_b(unsigned int index) = 0;
  protected:  
    int a;
};

class Child1
: public Parent
{
  public:
    int get_b(unsigned int index)
    {
        return b[index];  // Should have index bounds checking.
    }
  private:
    int b[20];
};
```

The inheritance allows you to adjust the size and quantity of members of the Parent class.

Comment: The underlying problem is to allow runtime variability of the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - (not putting this in question since I'm not sure about it) Since it seems to me from the current answers that there is currently no better way than **over** allocation, I was wondering if this would help maintenance wise:

```
template <class BASE, class T>
class dynarray
{
public:
    BASE base;
    const size_t size;
    T data[1]; // will be over allocated

    static dynarray * create(size_t data_size)
    {
        return new(data_size) dynarray(data_size);
    }
    void operator delete(void *p)
    {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
private:
    void * operator new (size_t full_size, size_t actual)
    {
        if (full_size != sizeof(dynarray))
        {
            // inheritence changed size - allocate it all
            return ::operator new(sizeof(dynarray));
        }

        return ::operator new(sizeof(dynarray) + (actual-1)*sizeof(T));
    }
    void operator delete(void *p, size_t) // matching delete
    {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
    dynarray(size_t data_size) : size(data_size)
    {
    }
};
```

usage is a bit stilted, but possibly better though:

```
typedef dynarray<double,int,27> dyn;
dyn * x=dyn::create(7);
x->data[5]=28;
x->base=5.3;
```

EDIT: changed implementation from **under** alloaction to **over** allocation

Comment: "Under allocation," i.e. using less than `sizeof(T)` bytes for an object of type `T`, does not work. This class is fairly likely to crash, whereas you asked for standards-compliance. Please ask a new question, because answerers do not usually scan the answers for one by the questioner.

Comment: @Potatoswatter How is this any more likely to crash than `int * x = new int[5]`.  I can find no place that requires that you allocate at least sizeof(T) for any class T, neither in standards nor in implementation.  It is only required that you do not access any memory past the amount allocated.  And I tested this and it worked.

Comment: The implementation is allowed to store its own data in padding at the end of a class type. Did you actually check the standard at all? §3.8/1 ("Object lifetime", paragraph 1) says "The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
— storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained…" This is the first thing you should have seen when looking it up.

Comment: @Potatoswatter  I interpreted proper size differently (its not defined directly), where i should have looked is under allocation - where it does say return a minimum of requested size (the first argument) - Argh.   So then it seems there is no standard way to under allocate.  And over allocating "struct hack" has theoretically untyped data access, but is that strictly not allowed?

Comment: changed to Over allocation - for more comments

Comment: I don't understand… there is no question linked there or from your profile page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41193/discussion-between-glenn-teitelbaum-and-potatoswatter)

Answer (score 0):

another way to do that is to use placement new

```
#include <cstdlib>

class var
{
    ...
private:
    int a;
    int b[1];
};

var * x = new(malloc(sizeof(var) + (27-1)*sizeof(var::b))) var;
```

in this case, contructor is called on allocated memory

to delete the structure use:

```
x->~var(); // only if var have a destructor
free(x);
```

or better, add a delete operator to var and use delete:

```
struct var {
    ...
    operator delete(void* ptr) throw() { free(ptr); }
};
var * x = ...
delete x;
```

The best and proper approach is to use a static function to create instances and to privatize the constructor:
    class var
    {
    public:
        ...
        static var * create(int size, ) throw() {
            new(malloc(sizeof(var) + (27-1)*sizeof(b)))) var();
        }
        void operator delete(void *ptr) { free(ptr); }

```
private:
    int a;
    int b[1];
    var(<args>) { ... }
};

var * x = var::create(27);
delete x;
```

note: i use an array of size 1 because undeffined and 0 sized arrays are not supported by all compilators.

Answer (score -2):

There was a defect report filed on this here for C: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_051.html

The response is that declaring the array to be the largest size you will need (or actually you can also do the maximum possible size for an integer as well) is a "safer idiom" and that it is strictly conforming. The idea is that, instead of *over* allocating and thus running beyond the declared size of the array, you actually *under* allocate and only access memory inside the declared bounds of the array.

This should apply to C++ as well as long as it didn't change those rules, which it shouldn't have because it's meant to be pretty much compatible with C. If someone knows something C++-specific that invalidates this solution, please inform me.

As long as you hide this implementation behind a well-defined interface, there shouldn't be any maintenance problems.

Comment: It doesn't work in C++ because it ties construction into the notion of lifetimes. The constructor for the class has the right to zero the memory for the entire array even if it's not required by the standard. There's no such thing as an object which exists without having storage for all its subobjects.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - seems pretty clear that this does conform and will work and mirrors the code I was trying to improve.   There is no reason to believe that if you are using this technique that you would write a constructor that goes past the virtual array boundry

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum What makes it clear that this conforms? The link at the top of the answer is for C, not C++.

Comment: @Potatoswatter you are correct: "The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of storage. If it is successful, it shall return the address of the start of a block of storage whose length in bytes shall be at least as large as the requested size."