# Dynamic array length in struct

Tags: c++, struct, b-tree

What I want to do is make a struct that has an array of another struct, and I want to set the size of the array at runtime. Is there any way to do that?
Struct is like:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  AnotherStruct list[];
  int key;
  bool isLeaf;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<AnotherStruct> list;`

Comment: Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641698/allocating-struct-with-variable-length-array-member or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969438/compliant-variable-length-struct-in-c

Comment: @IvanKukic Forgot to mention --  You need to post `AnotherStruct` before recommending to place it in a vector.  If it has correct copy semantics, then yes, `std::vector<AnotherStruct>` is safe to use.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah both of those questions, the answers are overcomplicated for this scenario (they assume the author didn't just want to use a vector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is:

```
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::vector<AnotherStruct> list;
    int key;
    bool isLeaf;
};
```

If you are new to vectors you can read about how to use them in any C++ reference.

Comment: I think he wants to avoid storing an extra pointer and size variable, like `std::vector` does.

Comment: I decided to go with this approach, checking if the vector has more elements than I want it to have at the time of adding elements to it.

Comment: @GillBates I didn't get that impression from the question, the requirements were stated fairly clearly in the first sentence. At any rate, it's not a bad approach to get the code working using straightforward code at first, and if you want to optimize for memory usage you can do that afterwards at a point where you're ready to profile and compare